# How do I list all packages belonging to a group (installed and uninstalled)?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I simply want to list of all packages belonging to a group (all, not only the installed ones), like there are listed on the website (for instance the [gnome group](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/gnome/)). Sure I could parse the HTML, but there should be / is for sure a build-in option that I most probably haven't found yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pacman -Sg gnome
```

Should do it, I believe.

From [`man 8 pacman`](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_sync_options_apply_to_em_s_em_a_id_so_a):

> #### Sync Options (apply to `-S`)
>
> ...
>   `-g`, `--groups`
>   Display all the members for each package group specified. If no group names are provided, all groups will be listed; pass the flag twice to view all groups and their members.